# valgrind for Raspbian (buster)

Tags: profiling, valgrind, raspbian

valgrind (3.7.0) on Raspbian (Version=10  (buster)) doesn't appear to work as it hangs upon invocation. It was installed using 'apt-get install valgrind'.  Here's the truncated output when invoked on /bin/ls. Note: there are many more warnings, and I have only listed the first 20 lines or so. Any ideas on what may be causing this and potential workarounds?

```
$ valgrind /bin/ls

==2116== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2116== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2116== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2116== Command: /bin/ls
==2116==
--2116-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--2116-- When reading debug info from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so:
--2116-- Ignoring non-Dwarf2/3/4 block in .debug_info
--2116-- WARNING: Serious error when reading debug info
--2116-- When reading debug info from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so:
--2116-- Last block truncated in .debug_info; ignoring
==2116== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2116==    at 0x401A5D0: index (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so)
==2116==
==2116== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2116==    at 0x401A5D4: index (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so)
==2116==
==2116== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2116==    at 0x4008040: _dl_dst_count (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so)
==2116==
==2116== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2116==    at 0x4008288: expand_dynamic_string_token (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so)
==2116==
==2116== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2116==    at 0x401AA80: strlen (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so)
==2116==
==2116== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2116==    at 0x401AA84: strlen (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so)
==2116==
==2116== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2116==    at 0x4017F68: malloc (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so)    
...
```

Comment: 3.7.0 is 9 years old, you should try the last version.

Comment: @phd: 3.7.0 is the latest version available through apt-get on Raspbian buster. What's the minimum version that fixes the issue I'm facing.

Comment: the best is to try to just released version (3.16.1).  Either your problem is fixed in this release, or it is unlikely that someone will fix an older release.

Comment: Yes, I tried 3.16.1, and it does not exhibit this issue. Thanks!